# How can I determine what the stats of ascended armor will be?

Tags: destiny

When an armor piece is ascended, its stats are increased to match the highest level gear that is currently available. Without actually ascending the item, is there any way to tell what its final stats will be? Obviously light will be 42 - I'm interested in the other stats on the item.

For example, if I have gauntlets with 36 Light, 52 Intellect, and 49 Discipline, once they are ascended how much Intellect and Discipline will they have?

Comment: Are you sure you're not interested in the other stats? Because if you're not interested in the other stats, I'm not sure what the question is about.

Comment: Just to be clear, the question is: "When I ascend a piece of armor, what will the new stat value be of the non-light stat?"

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Sorry for the poor wording. I added an example - does that help?

Comment: My comment was to the word "not" you had in there to begin with, you said you knew how light was affected and that you did not care about the other stats. :)

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Ah yes, that would be confusing. :) That was a typo on my part - looks like it was fixed with an edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's around a 6% increase, but it seems that there is some rounding going on somewhere as it's not always exactly a 6% increase. For example, if you had a helmet with 36 light and 100 intellect and you ascended it to 42 light, you can expect the new max intellect value to be about 106-107 intellect.

Comment: I was doing some additional testing, and found similar findings. I also ascended one piece from the Vault of Glass, and its stats increased by about 15%.

Answer (score 0):

There is no clear way to determine what the Intellect and Discipline will go to once you ascend your armour. Any exotics and legendary items that you get after the HoW DLC will tell you what it will be.

For example the Light Beyond Nemesis has 36-42 light and 102-142 intellect. The Light Beyond Nemesis will go to that light level and that intellect, but if you had it maxed before HoW you won't know what the intellect, discipline or strength will go to.

I hope this helped.

Comment: I know that once I ascend the item, I can see its max stats. The purpose of my question is to figure out what the stats will be when I have an item that isn't ascended yet. If have have a helm with intellect and discipline with 42 light (but they are a low roll, for example), it would be nice to know if this new helm I got that also has intellect and discipline will end up with higher values or not.

Comment: I know what you mean, but I don't know how to really explain it. If the armour has def upgrades then the intellect and discipline will change. If the armour doesn't have the def upgrades then the intellect will stay at what is given. Was this more helpful

Comment: I'm not asking about how much the stats will increase as I unlock the bubbles when leveling up the item. I'm asking how much the stats will change if the item is fully leveled up already, and I ascend it using an etheric light.